# Having trouble understanding methods parameters

Tags: c#, linq, methods, parameters, lambda

I'm sort of new to C#, but starting to get some understanding over lambda expression and over what delegates is and how they work.

But one thing I'm not 100% on board with is how to "read" the functions parameters.

Example.

In a string I have, I wanted to split the numbers and the letters. I got help from this with this expression.

```
 tempstring = numberBox.Text;
 tempnumber = tempstring.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToString();
```

I understand what it do, but when I look at the method `Where()`I have no idea what I'm looking at. When I hover over it gives me this text

`IEnumerable<char>IEnumerable<char>.Where<char>(Func<char, bool> predicate)(+1 overload)`

I'm not sure what to pick up from this. I know in the parameters of `Func<char, bool>` It wants a `Char` as input and will give `boolean` as output, but I don't know what to make of the rest. Is there any document to direct me or someone who can explain this in a average level ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @DavidG Already looked at it, but I can't really grasp it.

Comment: @Bojje since you are new to C# ,so initially assume that you have to do this way, and continue your learning on C#, all your assumption will be cleared when you cover Generics,Delegates and other advance features... but for now assume that it is the way you have to do things.

Comment: @ShekharPankaj You mean I just have to continue to read up on this? Even though I don't fully understand it?

Comment: If I understand well, what's confusing you is the <> notation ? There are for generics. They are used to specify "a type which is not known at building time". Thanks to it it's possible to define a method only one time but to make it able to take some different types of parameters, depending of the intended use, as long as they share some common behavior. You should read a tutorial about generics, it will help a lot.

Comment: @AFract Thank you. I've read up on generics (probably not all) but atleast  I understand that it's for a "type-based" security or something like that. What throws me off is Where<char> as you say. Does it say <char> because of the `ToCharArray()` ?

Comment: @Bojje There are several C# features in play here (Generics, Extension methods, Lambda expressions), so if you're new to it, it can be a lot to take in at once. C# is not something you can just pick up in a few days, especially the more advanced features. I always refer people to this YouTube channel: this guy explains things very clearly and in a funny way (even though the channel hasn't been updated in a while). I think the playlists relevant to this question are "C# Generics", "C# - Delegates, Lambda Expressions, and Events" and "C# Linq". https://www.youtube.com/user/1kingja/playlists

Comment: @Bojje remember your pre-school days,where you were remembering mathematical tables for 2 to 20 , at that time it was difficult to explain multiplication so they were asked to remember , so in this case assume those are thing which you will understand after learning Generics which will come at some point in near future of you Learning Journey ,and that time you will understand those on merely a glance on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to understand `.Where()` is a [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) extension method from .NET 3.5. It acts as a **filter** to `IEnumerable<T>`, which in your case, `T` is `char`. So basically, your expression:

```
tempnumber = tempstring.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToString();
```

is taking `tempstring` and converting to a `char[]` (which implements `IEnumerable<char>`, thus LINQ-enabled) and **filtering** the resulting sequence so that only `char`s fulfilling the predicate (`Char.IsDigit(c)` returning `true`) are returned. Finally `ToString()` is called to the resulting sequence.

To put it in a diagram, consider when `"Foo123"` is assigned to `tempstring`:

```
          ToCharArray()
"Foo123"        ->      ['F', 'o', 'o', '1', '2', '3']    -> ['F',              'o'   ...              ]     ->  ['1' ,'2', '3']  -> ToString()
   ^                                                           ^                 ^
   |                                                           |                 |
  tempstring                                                Char.IsDigit()    Char.IsDigit()
```

*By the way*, since `.Where` expects a `Func<char, bool>` and `Char.IsDigit` has the same method signature, you can shorten it:

```
tempnumber = tempstring.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsDigit).ToString()
```

There is no need to create another anonymous method to invoke `Char.IsDigit`.

Also, you can skip the `ToCharArray()` call because `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`. Thus, it can be simplified to:

```
tempnumber = tempstring.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToString();
```

Comment: Aha So this is why I'm getting Where<char> ? And if I wanted to make it into another array of another type (like int) I would get Where<int> ?

Comment: @Bojje, `.Where` is a generic method that takes a sequence (`IEnumerable<T>`) and a predicate (`Func<T, bool>`), and returns a filtered `IEnumerable<T>`. So yes, if you have an `int` array, you can invoke something like `new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Where(x => x < 3)` and `.Where` will have the generic parameter `int` here.

Comment: Okey. Not all upp to what predicate is but I'll read up more on it. Thank you so much for this! I would put you as an answer but already put it to another one. But thank you so much!

Comment: @Bojje, no problem. Predicate is just another fancy term for a **condition**, i.e. some method that returns a `bool`. When the predicate is passed together with the `IEnumerable<T>` to `.Where`, all elements are evaluated to this predicate/condition. Those satisfying the condition (returning `true`) will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already pointed out, the `Where` expects a predicate, which get as an input a char and returns a bool.

The notation `c => Char.IsDigit(c)` is a shorthand for this. It's a lambda expression, which it can be read as for the input `c` return true if `c` is a digit. Otherwise return false.

The left part of this expression (before the sign of `=>`) is the input and the right part of this expression is the output.

What is `c`?

Let's note this, `tempstring.ToCharArray()`. The later will convert the string that `tempstring` points to, to an array of `char`. Since an array object implements the `IEnumerable` interface, you can make use of the extension method called `Where` to filter the elements of the array. Writing the following:

```
tempstring.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c))
```

you say pick up only the characters of this array that are digits. So `c` it is corresponded with the random character in this array.

Comment: Yes, but what does the Where<char> stands for ? And all the other IEnumerable <char> before that ?

Comment: @DavidG Generics is where some about strongly-typed parameters right?

IEnumerable<T> is non-generic and IEnumerable<String> is a generic?

Comment: @Bojje Google is your friend... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @DavidG This doesn't help at all. You're just giving me links of stuff I've already read. I asked a question here to get a different "view" from what the documentation is giving me.

Comment: @Bojje Stackoverflow is not a resource to ask for tutorials on things, we have specific close reasons for just that.

Comment: @DavidG Asking for tutourials is asking on how to make it. I'm not asking how to create a thing, I'm asking for a different view in a subject that I don't understand, and can't figure out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is a Lambda expression of which you can find more information here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397687.aspx

You are passing to "Where" a function that defines the comparison to be made on the items that make up your Char array. You are stating that "c" is the item in the list (the char), and you want "c" to be returned if it matches your comparison (the bool).

The bool you are supplying in this case is "Char.IsDigit(c)". This comparison is applied to every item in the list (the Char array), and any that return true are returned to you.